# Purged package still choking the system

Tags: apt, package-management, fan

Some days ago I booted my dual-boot machine in Windows and, with my surprise, the fan was quieter.

Back to Linux I started investing what is going one, and it went out that was a process hogging all the CPUs' forces:
[Screenshot of the shell running top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8fDm.png)

The process was named `postgres`

I killed that process with `sudo kill 6509`

The fan slowed down and I thought that all was done.

But the next day the fan was noisy again. `top` showed that a process named `postgres`, was still there (different pid).

So

1. I killed the process;
2. purged postgresql: `sudo apt purge postgres*`.
   After that I reboot but a process named `postgres` using a lot of CPU was there.

I think it can't be something postgresql's related.

How can I remove it?

Comment: What is the output of `apt list | grep postgres`?

Comment: Try `systemctl list-units --type=service` to see if you have a systemd service for postgres. If so, use `sudo systemctl stop <service-name>.service` to halt without respawning. Use `sudo systemctl disable <service-name>.service` to prevent restarting at boot.

Comment: @Paul I got a lot lines `apt list | grep postgres | wc -l \n WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts. \n 151`

Comment: @user535733 in the list there isn't anything similar  to postgres

Comment: When `postgres` is running, try `ps -aux | grep postgres` to find exactly which command is starting the process. Also try `pstree` to see what's launching postgres. Please avoid adding output in comments. Add output in your question instead, where you can properly format the output. Comments are how we ask you for additional information and clarifications. Comments get deleted, so don't put key information in comments.

Comment: @user535733 using `ps` or using `top` I got the father process: I already knew it was `kswap0` which, in turn, has as father `kswap`. I think the "k" stands for "kernel" and killing the anchestor process doesn't seem such a good idea to me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem was kswap, I start looking for that; I red a very similar issue in this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/3956962/kswapd-using-100-of-cpu). In that they suggest to limit the resources available for the user that keeps hogging the system.

In my case that user was `postgres` but I have already purged all the packages.

The hint was the  word **user**; I checked the file `/etc/passwd` and, even if the packages were purged, the user was still there.

I removed the user from `/etc/passwd`, reboot, and problem is over :) .

*( Note: this ok bacause I don't use postgresql anymore, otherwise you have to follow the other thread's solution. )*